# How to set no proxy in yarn

Tags: yarnpkg

I am trying to install packages from within the corporate network along with some packages that exist within the corporate repository. I was able to configure the following proxy settings for yarn

```
yarn config set proxy "${PROXY}"
yarn config set https-proxy "${PROXY}"
```

But since some packages exist within the corporate network installing them fails. I couldnt find a way to set no proxy for internal corporate urls. There is a workaround posted here - https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/5048#issuecomment-604181595. But I would like to know if there is a better way

Answer (score 1):

yarn doesn't seem to to have a concept of no proxy.  It either tries to proxy everything or nothing...very naive.  Fortunately, npm does so we use npm for all of our projects.